# how to display alphabet patterns on same line in java?

Tags: java

I have designed different patterns(alphabet) in java and I want then all to print in one single horizontal line(trying to print a name using pattern logic). My program is showing the output in vertical line. Here is my code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

/** M **/
int fp = 0;
int sp = 0;

//outer loop
for (int row = 1; row <= 10; row++) {
for (int col = 1; col <= 11; col++) {
if (col == 1 || col == 11 || (col == fp || col == sp) && row <= 10 / 2 + 1) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
            if (row == 1) {
                fp = 1;
                sp = 11;
            }
            fp++;
            sp--;
        }


/** A **/

int afp=20/2;
int asp=20/2;

for (int row=1; row<=10; row++ ) {
for (int col = 1; col <= 20; col++) {
if (col == afp || col==asp || row==10/2 && col>afp && col<asp && col%2==0) {
                   System.out.print("*");
               } else {
                   System.out.print(" ");
               }
           }
           System.out.println();
           afp--;
           asp++;

       }


    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't add unrelated language tags. If you have a question about java, then there is no reason to add tags for c#, python etc.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please [edit] your question to include your desired input and the input you're getting instead. Also, please do everyone (including yourself) a favor and format your code correctly.

Comment: If each character that is printed was instead placed into a 2D Array, how would you merge those 2D Arrays together to make the characters print horizontally?